# my html code works perfectly on my computer but not in browser

Tags: html

[incorrect display in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwcYx.jpg)

My html code works perfectly on my computer (local) but when I upload it to a server and view it in a browser, it doesn't display correctly.  Specifically, I am building an 8 image photo gallery.  Here's the code.  Can you help me identify the problem?

```
    <!--Start section-->
  <section class="well well-bottom-null text-center">
    <div class="container container-wide">
    <h1>Services</h1> 
    <hr>

     <div data-lightbox="gallery" class="row row-no-gutter offset-2">

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="img-thumbnail text-center"><a href="images/strategy1.jpg" data-lightbox="image"><img src="images/strategy1.jpg" alt="" class="img-wide">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h1>Strategic & Business Planning</h1>
                  <p>Proforma P&L Budgeting, <br> Business Plans</p>
                </div><span class="overlay"></span></a></div>
               </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="img-thumbnail text-center"><a href="images/competitive.jpg" data-lightbox="image"><img src="images/competitive.jpg" alt="" class="img-wide">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h1>Competitive Analysis</h1>
                  <p>Situation Analysis, Virtual Market Surveys, Market Research</p>
                </div><span class="overlay"></span></a></div>
               </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="img-thumbnail text-center"><a href="images/lead.jpg" data-lightbox="image"><img src="images/lead.jpg" alt="" class="img-wide">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h1>Lead Generation</h1>
                  <p>Inbound Marketing</p>
                </div><span class="overlay"></span></a></div>
               </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="img-thumbnail text-center"><a href="images/web-design.jpg" data-lightbox="image"><img src="images/web-design.jpg" alt="" class="img-wide">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h1>Website Design</h1>
                  <p>Design, Content Generation, SEO</p>
                </div><span class="overlay"></span></a></div>
                </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="img-thumbnail text-center"><a href="images/social.jpg" data-lightbox="image"><img src="images/social.jpg" alt="" class="img-wide">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h1>Social Media Marketing</h1>
                  <p>Social Relevance <br> Social Engagement</p>
                </div><span class="overlay"></span></a></div>
                </div>

           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="img-thumbnail text-center"><a href="images/blog.jpg" data-lightbox="image"><img src="images/blog.jpg" alt="" class="img-wide">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h1>Content Generation</h1>
                  <p>Videos, Blogs, E-books, Articles</p>
                </div><span class="overlay"></span></a></div>
                </div>

           <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="img-thumbnail text-center"><a href="images/promo.jpg" data-lightbox="image"><img src="images/promo.jpg" alt="" class="img-wide">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h1>Marketing Collateral & Promotion</h1>
                  <p>Brochures, Post Cards, Flyers, Promotional Items</p>
                </div><span class="overlay"></span></a></div>
                </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="img-thumbnail text-center"><a href="images/events.jpg" data-lightbox="image"><img src="images/events.jpg" alt="" class="img-wide">
                <div class="caption">
                  <h1>Corporate Events</h1>
                  <p>Trade Shows, Sales Meetings, <br> Customer Appreciation, <br>Team Building</p>
                </div><span class="overlay"></span></a></div>
                </div>


        </div> 
       </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Have you tried different browsers and clearing the cache

Comment: Set a consistent fixed height on all of the images so the wrapping does not get goofed up.

Comment: The way you reference the images, the folder images/ is expected to be a subfolder of the current one - the one your page lives. I find it more convenient using relative paths, e.g. /images/ or /path/to/images/

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I have cleared the cache.  I have tried two different browsers. All the images are consistent sizes (1000 x 800 pix)  It works when they are small, i.e. 200x 150 but then the effect of the light box enlargement is lost.   if you want to view it live  http://mbt-marketing.com/  thanks.  Also thanks for the tip on the paths.

Comment: also wanted to mention I validated the code with W3c

Answer (score 0):

It could be many things, but I would start making sure the bootstrap folder is uploaded to your server and not just on your local machine.

If this is not the problem, than it is something within your CSS.